# What's the driver version for my ATI graphics card?

Tags: drivers, radeon, ati

How do I find out if I have the latest driver for an ATI Radeon HD 5770 graphics card?  The AMD website has the ATI driver 11.8 but before I try to install it, I'd like to find out whether I already have it installed or not.

Comment: Have you resolved your question?

Comment: I think that [How does the fglrx version relate to AMD version?](http://askubuntu.com/q/121185/8570) will be useful to you because the driver version information returned by the commands below may not match/show the Catalyst version.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick for you:

```
cat /etc/ati/amdpcsdb | grep "Catalyst_Version"
```

You should see something like

```
Catalyst_Version=S11.4
```

(Thanks for the question, it reminds me to update my display driver.)

Comment: Nice.  Didn't know about that one.

Comment: For fglrx driver I found `grep "Version"` was required as there was no _Catalyst_Version_ just _ReleaseVersion_.

Answer (score 1):

Check your X.org logs to see the version of the currently running graphic driver:

```
less /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is `aptitude show fglrx`.