# How does the fglrx package's version relate to AMD's version numbers, like Catalyst 12.3?

Tags: drivers, package-management, fglrx, ati

When I learn about a new version of AMD's graphics driver, I usually see something like "[Catalyst 12.3](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)." However, the fglrx package in Ubuntu has a version like 2:8.960-0.

Are these two version numbers related? How can I find the (better-known) official version number, like 12.3, for the fglrx package in Ubuntu's repository?
Can I do this without needing to install the package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Unofficial AMD Linux Driver Wiki**](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Category%3aReleases) has the driver version on the release pages. e.g. [Catalyst 12.3](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Catalyst_12.3):

```
Revision Number: 12.3 (8.951)
```

---

Alternatively the [**Catalyst RSS Feed**](http://www2.ati.com/rss/catalyst.rss) for Microsoft Windows also contains the driver information.

```
Catalyst 12.3 released for Windows. Available at 
http://game.amd.com/28/03/12 13:21
Driver version: 8.951
```

Comment: That feed is outdated indeed, but I've seen that they posted the released Catalyst version together with the actual driver release number. So, it's just a matter of update though... Anyway, I give positive vote here, because the initial question is answered very well. Thanks for the information. It was quite helpful and useful. Cheers, Sniper.

Comment: Great, that answers my question! I guess I never thought to look more deeply on the Windows download page :)

Comment: It looks like that detail isn't added to those pages so often now. 13.4 from April 2013 seems like the last update (12.104).