# How can I determine which version of AMD Catalyst is installed?

Tags: fglrx, ati, catalyst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the fglrx package's version relate to AMD's version numbers, like Catalyst 12.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121185/how-does-the-fglrx-packages-version-relate-to-amds-version-numbers-like-catal)

All official AMD documents refer to the AMD proprietary graphics driver by the Catalyst name and version. In the Ubuntu repository the driver is referred to only by the fglrx name and version. As a result, it is impossible to determine whether official AMD documents apply or not.

Is there a log somewhere which includes the Catalyst version? Perhaps some command? Since the machine is headless I would prefer a terminal-only command.

If not, where can I find a list of which fglrx versions are equivalent to which Catalyst versions?