# How can I check the installed AMD Catalyst driver version?

Tags: drivers, ati

How can I check the installed AMD Catalyst driver version from the terminal? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 9):

`dmesg | grep fglrx | grep module` will output something including a line with something like `module loaded - fglrx 9.0.2 [Sep 20 2012]`. The `9.0.2` part is the Catalyst version.

Note: in order to compare the fglrx package's version to AMD's version numbers, see [How does the fglrx package's version relate to AMD's version numbers, like Catalyst 12.3?](https://askubuntu.com/q/121185/5696).

Comment: added a small change to command that will have the output limited to 2 lines instead  of a whole screen ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you installed `fglrx` from the repositories or via a deb you can get the version from `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache policy fglrx
```

this will give

```
fglrx:
  Installed: 2:9.012-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2:9.012-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2:9.012-0ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1 0
       500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     2:8.960-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted amd64 Packages
```

As you can see I installed version 9.012 (from a deb I made from the amd site) and the version in the repositories is 8.960.

Or you could do Jeff's solution which also works if you didn't install using `apt` (not installing with apt is not recommended!).

Answer (score 2):

on my system AMD Catalyst Linux 13.1 driver Revision Number: **13.1 (9.012)** 
shows for your command a different **fglrx** version then **fglrxinfo**. just FYI.

```
t@t-ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep fglrx | grep module
[    3.768319] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[    3.839422] [fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 9.1.11 [Dec 19 2012] with 1 minors

t@t-ubuntu:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5800 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12002 Compatibility Profile Context 9.012
```