# To which catalyst version correspond the fglrx-update drivers of 14.04

Tags: ati, 14.04, fglrx, catalyst

I cant get my head with the version number of catalyst and fglrx. I had 12.04 with 13.1 catalyst and upgraded to 14.04 and selected from the Additional Drivers Tab the fglrx update driver. To which catalyst version does this correspond to?

Comment: explained here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121185/how-does-the-fglrx-packages-version-relate-to-amds-version-numbers-like-catal

Comment: my question is specific for 14.04

Comment: how does that matter? The answer explains how to find out in a generic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same version of Ubuntu and I installed the same drivers.

I think you have a couple of ways to determine the catalyst version:

1. use `amdcccle` and under the Information tab you get the software version
2. look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` the version of the most recent `fglrx` package you installed.

Whatever you choose, the answer to your question (as of today) is catalyst 13.35.